# Asp Identity navigation property

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-identity, navigation-properties

How can I ipmlement this sql code

```
select u.* from AspNetUsers u join AspNetUserRoles ur on u.Id=ur.UserId join AspNetRoles r on r.Name='client' and r.Id=ur.RoleId;
```

in c# using only the default (if there is) asp navigation properties?
These tables are the default auto generated tables.

Comment: Do you use the Entity Framework or you want a result using a list which is filled with this table details?

Comment: yes, I use Entity Framework and I would like to get back an IEnumerable<Client>

Comment: Do you know the DB Context, getting the DB objects and LINQ?

Answer (score 0):

Probably this one you are looking for

```
DataContext = context = new DataContext();

var result = 
from au in context.AspNetUsers 
join ur in context.AspNetUserRoles on au.Id Equals ur.UserId
join r in context.AspNetRoles.Where(x=>x.Name='client') on r.Id Equals ur.RoleId
select au;
```

This is merely a sample query, perhaps the datacontext implementation is different in yours.

Comment: yeah it is the same what I wrote just in c#
it is LINQ not the navigation properties.
c# can do this for us if we use the nav. prop. I just not know how to

Comment: Could you please add the structure you have created. Perhaps, we can look into it and edit